# set date to iso format in sharepoint through the GUI

Tags: sharepoint

in sharepoint can i use calculated value on a date field to set the format of a date?
eg i want to set a date field to ISO format

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the TEXT() function in your calculated field, like this:

```
TEXT([NAMEOFYOURDATEFIELD],"yyyy-mm-dd")
```